# Do I need to check in *Prefix.pch to source control system?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am wondering if I need to check in *Prefix.pch to source control system?

In Windows, Pch is the precompiled header, but in XCode, it is a source file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a good idea to include your .pch file in your source control system.

[A .pch file is automatically included](http://www.lynnnayko.com/2013/02/what-is-pch-file-in-xcode.html) in every source file at compile time.